# Should processing be happening "behind" the alert?

Tags: swift, uialertcontroller

I am writing a routine to check if a file exists and if so alert the user and ask if I should overwrite.  I am getting what is to me is strange behavior.

Here is my code to write the file.

```
    if let jsonToSave = myFile.json {
            var shouldIOverwrite: Bool = false
          if let url = try? FileManager.default.url(
                for: .documentDirectory,
                in: .userDomainMask,
                appropriateFor: nil,
                create: true
                ).appendingPathComponent(name + ".json"){
                do {
                    print("place 1: \(shouldIOverwrite)")
                     shouldIOverwrite = presentOverwriteWarning(for: url, fName: name)
                    print("place 2: \(shouldIOverwrite)")
                    if shouldIOverwrite {   
                        try jsonToSave.write(to: url)
                        print("saved successfully")
                    }
                } catch let error {
                    print("couldn't save \(error)")
                }
            }
        }
```

Here is the function that sets and presents the alert:

```
private func presentOverwriteWarning(for url: URL?, fName: String) -> Bool {
    var overwrite: Bool = false

        let alert = UIAlertController(
            title: "File for \"" + fName + "\" exists",
            message: "Do you want to overwrite it?",
            preferredStyle: .alert
        )
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(
            title: "Yes",
            style: .default,
            handler: { action in
                 overwrite = true
        }
        ))
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(
            title: "No",
            style: .default,
            handler: { action in
                overwrite = false
        }
        ))
        present(alert, animated: true)

    return overwrite
}
```

I am returning Bool value overwrite.  Notice I have two print commands "place 1" and "place 2".  As I debug what I am seeing is that the 2 prints are already listed in the output as false before my alert is on my screen before it is responding.  So my "if overwrite " is always false.  Am I missing something on my alert?

Note: you will see there is no code to check if the file exists yet.  For debugging I am always calling the alert.

Comment: The code inside `alert.addAction(handler` is asynchronous (executed in parallel to your code), and you're reading `overwrite` before it was changed by `UIAlertController`. I'd suggest sending `Notification` when you change `overwrite`, and execute your code inside that notification listener method.

Comment: Thank you I did not realize alerts were asynchronous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would change your presentOverwriteWarning function to use a callback, instead of having it return anything, since the alert is asynchronous:

```
private func presentOverwriteWarning(for url: URL?, fName: String, callback: (Bool) -> Void) {
    let alert = UIAlertController(
        title: "File for \"" + fName + "\" exists",
        message: "Do you want to overwrite it?",
        preferredStyle: .alert
    )
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(
        title: "Yes",
        style: .default,
        handler: { action in
            callback(true)
    }
    ))
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(
        title: "No",
        style: .default,
        handler: { action in
            callback(false)
    }
    ))
    present(alert, animated: true)
}
```

You can then use it like this:

```
presentOverwriteWarning(for: url, fName: name) { overwrite in
    if (overwrite) {
         try jsonToSave.write(to: url)
    }
}
```

UPDATE: To fix the compile error related to the try jsonToSave, you need to move the do-catch block:

```
presentOverwriteWarning(for: url, fName: name) { overwrite in
    if (overwrite) {
         do {
            try jsonToSave.write(to: url)
         } catch {

         }
    }
}
```

Comment: andlin, interesting approach.  I am not very familiar with using callbacks.  Implementing it I have run into two problems.  The first seemed easy enough.  I have to add "@escaping" to the func.  As in:

func presentOverwriteWarning(for url: URL?, fName: String, callback: @escaping (Bool) -> Void)

The second problem is more problematic.   The "try jsonToSave.write(to: url)" is giving me an error:  Invalid conversion from throwing function of type '(_) throws -> ()' to non-throwing function type '(Bool) -> Void'

Thoughts on solving this?

Comment: @jz_ Adding escaping is perfectly normal and expected. :) I have updated my answer regarding the throw related error

Comment: the fix to the throw corrects the error.  I have accepted this answer.